# Non-trivial designated initializers

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am currently working on an OS and working on the utils section. Specifically, on the tmp dir. I have came up with this code,

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#define HIGH_KERNEL   0xc0000000
#define PAGE_SIZE     4096
#define PAGE_PRESENT  (1 << 0)
#define PAGE_WRITE    (1 << 1)
#define PAGE_HUGE     (1 << 7)

__attribute__((__aligned__(PAGE_SIZE)))
uint32_t tmp_pgdir[1024] = {
  [0] = 0x0 | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE | PAGE_HUGE,
  [HIGH_KERNEL >> 22] = 0x0 | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE | PAGE_HUGE,
};
```

Now, afaik non-trivial designated initializers are *not* supported in C++, so one option I thought of is compiling the file as a `C` file. Now, I wonder, is there a workaround? Is it actually the ideal solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Both Clang and GCC support designated initializers as extensions when compiling C++ code.

Comment: I am indeed using gcc. I might have mistakenly thought it doesn't, oddly. I'll recheck it.

Comment: Looks like I was partially mistaken. Only clang offers them as an extension when compiling C++ code. GCC supports them as an extension for C standards pre C99, not but in C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[/*...*/] =`  initializer syntax for arrays isn't standard C++ at all.

But you don't need it in C++. You can just initialize the array in the same way that you would do it at block scope with the help of an immediately-invoked lambda and `std::array`:

```
alignas(PAGE_SIZE) constinit auto tmp_pgdir = []{
  std::array<std::uint32_t, 1024> ret{}; // {} initializes to zero
  ret[0] = 0x0 | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE | PAGE_HUGE;
  ret[HIGH_KERNEL >> 22] = 0x0 | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE | PAGE_HUGE;
  return ret;
}();
```

`alignas(PAGE_SIZE)` is the standard-C++ form for the alignment attribute.

`constinit` assures that the initialization happens at compile-time, not runtime. It makes the compiler complain if initialization at compile-time is not possible.

`std::array` has the benefit of having the normal function passing behavior of non-array object types, so it can be returned from the function directly.

The lambda is not strictly necessary. If you prefer this can be a `constexpr` named function to be called in the initializer as well.

The above requires C++20 for `constinit`, otherwise only C++14. But without `constinit` you are yourself responsible for making sure that the initialization can be done at compile-time, i.e. is a constant expression. In particular, if you don't use a lambda, you are then responsible for assuring that the function that you call is actually marked `constexpr`.

All of the `#define` constants can be `constexpr auto` variables in C++ instead as well. There is no good reason to `#define` such constants in C++11 and later (except if you need them in the preprocessor or a header shared with C sources).

Also, if you don't intent to modify `tmp_pgdir`, then declare it `constexpr` instead of `constinit`. This, in addition to assuring compile-time initialization, will make the variable non-modifiable as well and gets rid of the C++20 requirement for `constinit`.

In order to obtain a pointer to the beginning of the array use `tmp_pgdir.data()`, `&tmp_pgdir[0]` or `std::to_address(std::begin(tmp_pgdir))` instead of just `std::begin(tmp_pgdir)`, `&tmp_pgdir` or `tmp_pgdir`. `&tmp_pgdir` will probably also work if the target isn't aware of the pointer type, but it is formally wrong. `std::begin(tmp_pgdir)` directly may or may not work depending on implementation details.

To get a pointer to one-past-the end use `std::to_address(std::end(tmp_pgdir))` or `tmp_pgdir.data() + std::size(tmp_pgdir)`. Again, just `&tmp_pgdir + 1` or `std::end(tmp_pgdir)` or `&tmp_pgdir[std::size(tmp_pgdir)]` will probably work as well, but are formally incorrect or implementation-dependent.

Comment: I'll check it and accept your answer if it will work. Thanks!